# Is there a way a function automatically detects data type of its arguments? (Please don't suggest function overloading)

Tags: c++, function, type-conversion, overloading

What I'm trying to do is as follows:

```
 (some data type say x) function_name((same data type x mentioned earlier) variable_name) 
 {
 /* Function body */
 }

 int main()
 {
 (data type x mentioned above) var;
 function_name(var);
 .....
 }
```

for example I've

```
 int function_name(int x)

 int main()
 {
 int y;
 function_name(y);
 ....}
```

In main(), I pass an int variable through above function
 Now I want another function of exactly same body as above function, but just differ in data type of arguments and return type, say

```
unsigned long long FUNCTION_NAME_SAME_DEFINITION_AS_function_name(unsigned long long x)
```

Is there a way I can merge the above two functions, without using function overloading? Mean the function detects what data type of variable is passed through it? if I pass argument of type 1 it returns value of data type 1 and if I pass argument of type 2 it returns value of data type 2 .

Answer (score 8):

You mean like a template?

```
template <typename T>
T function_name(T variable_name) 
{
    /* Function body */
}
```

read a book or something.

Comment: Can T take int,unsigned long long,...like this data types here?

Comment: @UserCPP Yes it can; and the most important part of this answer is the last sentence.

Comment: @UserCPP And no - there will be a distinct function for each type

Comment: Yes, It seems like I'm looking for this only.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with templates.

```
template <typename T>
T function_name(T var) {
    // code
}

int main() {
    int foo;
    char bar;

    function_name(foo); // returns int
    function_name(bar); // returns char
}
```

The compiler will attempt various type combinations with the available template definitions to output a valid function.  If it is successful, it will generate a complete function definition with that type.

**In reply to:** UserCPP: Is it possible? template T function_name{....}, Mean function accepts no data type and in main function I write "variable = function_name()"

This is not possible directly.  Function templates can only deduce types from arguments, NOT from return values.  You have some options.  You could modify by reference rather than returning a value:

```
template <typename T>
void function_name(T& var) {
    // code
}

int main() {
    int foo;
    char bar;

    function_name(foo); // modifies foo as an int
    function_name(bar); // modifies bar as a char
}
```

You could also explicitly state the type:

```
template <typename T>
T function_name() {
    // code
}

int main() {
    int foo;
    char bar;

    foo = function_name<int>();  // returns int
    bar = function_name<char>(); // returns char
}
```

**Recommended reading:**

[Function templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) (Specifically, [Argument Deduction in Function Templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Template_argument_deduction))

Comment: Is it possible? template<typename T> T function_name{....}, Mean function accepts no data type and in main function I write "variable = function_name()"

Comment: @UserCPP I edited my post with an answer, short answer is no, but there are options.